# AppEngine Entities and management

Tags: sql, google-app-engine

I am going to use App engine for my app i am building.

I am doing something like this.. from the app the user enters in information

```
class Employee(db.Model):
  first_name = db.StringProperty()
  last_name = db.StringProperty()
  hire_date = db.DateProperty()

  location = db.StringProperty();

  attended_hr_training = db.BooleanProperty()


employee = Employee(first_name='Antonio',
                last_name='Salieri')

employee.hire_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
employee.attended_hr_training = True

employee.put()
```

Once the user is inserted i would like the user to receive a number that it is identified while it is in the database.

I would then like to notify the PC app that a new user has been added and then the PC will have the ability to send a something to the app and the message goes to the correct ID that the message was intended for.

Is this possible with App Engine?

EDIT:

i would like to have a main PC App that connects to each entity that gets notified when a new entry is made.

Comment: yes everything you mention is possible. you only need to start reading the docs... there are a lot of examples for how to do things. i would suggest you read the documentation first instead of asking questions like these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain what you mean by "number that is identified".

You can store a record key like `emp_key = employee.put()` That will let you access that record without doing a database query.  If that is what you mean.

As far as notifying "PC app" depends on what the app is capable of.  You can use channels, or xmpp to send the notice.  The PC App could query the datastore periodically.  There are lots of ways to do that.  You send the PC App the record key as a string that it can return in the request to get the record.

Although to be honest a PC app is so 1990.  You probably should be using a web browser in which case go to my [AE-BaseApp/Python](http://ae-baseapp.appspot.com/python) click the Github link and go check out the source code.  Examples of everything your asking for is there.  It is still a very basic app I am working on that demonstrates how to do things in App Engine.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! You are correct. I think i will do the "PC APP" web based. So if i do it this way, how easy would it be to add the new created "Entry" to the list that the user in the web browser sees? Just by the click of a simple refresh button?

Comment: I also would need multiple users to have access to see the list of entries added to a specific Entitiy. I know would just query for this but what would i need to implement as far as allowing for multiple users access to the main panel to see all the entries in there certain Entitiy?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer there are lots of ways the main two would be [channel api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) for pushing the notice to the client, or [xmpp](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/) which would require the client have an xmpp interface.  

I haven't stubbed either of those out yet in AE-BaseApp, it will probably be a month or so.  You can take a look at sending an email from App Engine to notify a user that contains a record key that is used to update a record.  Then use the same basic process for Channel